# react-redux-thunk why is my async action not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The below code for an asynchronous action works does not work, i.e, the fetch works fine but the dispatch doesn't work. (Please see the output in the codesandbox link at the bottom.)

```js
function addUser(user) {
  return {
    type: FETCH,
    payload: { user }
  };
}

// action creator returns a function
export function fetchUser(githubUserName) {
  console.log("fetching...");
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios(`https://api.github.com/users/${githubUserName}`).then(
      (user) => {
        // dispatch(addUser(user.data));
        let res = user.data;
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH,
          payload: { res }
        });
      }
    );
  };
}
```

If I uncomment the `dispatch(addUser(user.data));` and comment the below part

```js
let res = user.data;
dispatch({
  type: FETCH,
  payload: { res }
});
```

It works. I'm unable to get why the former does not work. Is there a way to make my dispatch work without using `dispatch(addUser(user.data))`?

Link to codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-with-redux-thunk-no-connect-used-jy5c77?file=/src/actions/fetch.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addUser` action creator function returns an action object with type `"FETCH"` and a `payload` property object with a `user` property.

```js
function addUser(user) {
  return {
    type: FETCH,
    payload: { user }
  };
}
```

The `dispatch(addUser(user.data));` call is working. Where the other code differs is in what is stored in the action payload.

```js
let res = user.data;
dispatch({
  type: FETCH,
  payload: { res }
});
```

Here you've hardcoded the action object with the same `type` property, but the `payload` property object has a `res` property. Change this to `user` and it also works.

```js
let res = user.data;
dispatch({
  type: FETCH,
  payload: { user: res }
});
```

Code

```js
export function fetchUser(githubUserName) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const { data } = await axios(
      `https://api.github.com/users/${githubUserName}`
    );
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH,
      payload: { user: data }
    });
  };
}
```

[image: Edit react-redux-thunk-why-is-my-async-action-not-working]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! But I am having trouble in understanding why this happens. Why is it required to pass `{ user: res }` as payload while we pass `user.data` as argument to addUser - `dispatch(addUser(user.data)`?

Comment: @GauthamMuralidharan In the `addUser` function you've saved the `user` function arg into the `action.payload` using the object assignment [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions), e.g. `{ user }` is the same as `{ user: user }`. You are using the shorthand notation in the other place, but using a variable named `res` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your codelines. It has one problem.
dispatch({
type: FETCH,
payload: { user: user.data }
});

you have to change like this.